# load javascripts from asset pipeline in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

In a rails project, I want just use controller and model of rails application. For this purpose, I use `angularjs`. I put my angularjs file in `assets/angular` directory and I route url and set templates from `app.js` in angular. Know I deactive rails view by below code in `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  def index
    render :layout => 'application', :nothing => true
  end
end
```

`config/routes.rb`:

```
  root to: 'application#index'
```

Know, when I run the server and project run on `localhost:3000`, my scripts don't load and `<head>` of html file is empty.

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
  <body>
   <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
   </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

This problem is about asset pipeline, and `js` don't load. How can I fixed this problem?

I have this code for angular:

`asset/javascripts/angular/app.js.erb`:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])
        .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                    .when('/',          {controller: 'ForumIndexController',    templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/index.html') %>'})
                    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
        }
        ]);
```

`view/layout/application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <title>SimpleForum</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular.min
//= require angular-resource.min
//= require ../angular/app
//= require_tree ../angular
```

How can I set rails application to load scripts?

Any Idea about fixed this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the ../ infront of the angular folder, since it is at the same level as the manifest.

```
//= require angular/app
//= require_tree angular
```

Should be fine.